# Cobol: Cannot Find What Is Causing Infinite Loop Error in File Matching

Tags: infinite-loop, cobol

I have been trying to  learn about file matching through school.  When going through my code I get an infinite loop but I am not exactly sure what is causing it. All I know it is somewhere in my file matching portion of code.

```
01 Procedure Division.  
02   A-Para.
03      Perform Process-Para Until EOFa = "Y"
04        and EOFb = "Y"
05   Process-Para.  
06       Add 1 to counter
07       
08       If inFileSorted-empNum = timeFileSorted-empNum
09           Perform check-Para
10       End-If.
11   
12   check-Para. 
13       Perform ReadTimeFile
14       If changeEmployee equals "Y"
15           Perform Compute-Para
16       End-If
17       If timeFileSorted-empNum not equal to inFileSorted-empNum
18           Perform ReadinFile
19           If changeEmployee equals "Y"
20               Perform Compute-Para
21           End-If
22       End-If
23       
24       Perform 510-Calculate
25       Perform Display-Para.
26
27    ReadTimeFile. 
28       Move spaces to changeEmployee
29       
30       If not EOFb = "Y"
31           Move timeFileSorted-empNum to oldEmpNum              
32           Read timeFileSort             
33           At end
34               Move "Y" to EOFb
35               Move high-value to timeFileSorted-empNum
36           Not at end
37               Move timeFileSorted-empNum to newEmpNum  
38               If (oldEmpNum not equal newEmpNum)
39                   Move "Y" to changeEmployee
40               End-If
41           End-Read
42       End-If.  
43
44    ReadinFile.  
45       Move spaces to changeEmployee
46       
47       If not EOFa = "Y"
48           Move inFileSorted-empNum to oldEmpNum
49           Read Lab10-sort-File
50           At end
51               Move "Y" to EOFa
52               Move high-value to inFileSorted-empNum                  
53           Not at end
54               Move inFileSorted-empNum to newEmpNum  
55               If (oldEmpNum not equal newEmpNum)
56                  Move "Y" to changeEmployee
57               End-If
58           End-Read
59       End-If.
```

Could someone help me find what could be causing this problem?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause (in Process-Para) is

```
08       If inFileSorted-empNum = timeFileSorted-empNum
09           Perform check-Para
10       End-If.
```

if inFileSorted-empNum **not** = timeFileSorted-empNum it will **skip** over check-Para and **not read either file**

---

#### better option

This is not intended to work but to show you how to structure the code. Please note at least one file is read each time through the loop

```
open infile, timefile
Perform read-inFile
Perform read-timeFile
perform until EOFa = "Y" or EOFb = "Y"
    evaluate true
    when inFileSorted-empNum < timeFileSorted-empNum
        ...
        Perform read-inFile
    when inFileSorted-empNum > timeFileSorted-empNum
        ...
        Perform read-timeFile
    when Other
       ...
        Perform read-timeFile  ???
    end-evaluate
end-perform

perform until EOFa = "Y"
    ...
end-perform

perform until EOFb not = "Y"
    ...
end-perform
.
```